# Always paste as a text in visual editor

Tags: editor

I am running a multi author blog. I allowed only visual editor for authors. So, i don't want to allow them to paste disallowed html tags from other source. I want, text will always paste as **plain text**. Please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function tinymce_paste_as_text( $init ) {
  $init['paste_as_text'] = true;
  return $init;
}

add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'tinymce_paste_as_text');
```

For details please follow link : [tiny_mce_before_init](http://wpseek.com/hook/tiny_mce_before_init/)

Thanks!